# Do I need to free these frames and if yes is it the right way?

Tags: delphi

Do I have to free these two frames in that case ? And if yes, is it the right way. I have a form in which there can be two differents frames that I can call with two buttons as you can see on the picture. I can call the one I want depending on the button I press.

Here are the procedures :

```pascal
procedure TChercherDesAppelsForm.OuvrirFrameChercherAppelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FrameStatistiquesAppels) then
  begin
    FrameStatistiquesAppels.Free;
  end;
  FrameChercherAppels := TChercherAppelsFrame.Create(nil);
  FrameChercherAppels.Top:=35;
  FrameChercherAppels.Parent:= ChercherDesAppelsForm;
end;

procedure TChercherDesAppelsForm.OuvrirFrameStatistiquesAppelsOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FrameChercherAppels) then
  begin
    FrameChercherAppels.Free;
  end;
  FrameStatistiquesAppels := TStatistiquesAppelsFrame.Create(nil);
  FrameStatistiquesAppels.Top:=35;
  FrameStatistiquesAppels.Parent:= ChercherDesAppelsForm;
end;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three issues with your code:

```
procedure TChercherDesAppelsForm.OuvrirFrameChercherAppelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FrameStatistiquesAppels) then
  begin
    FrameStatistiquesAppels.Free;
  end;
  FrameChercherAppels := TChercherAppelsFrame.Create(nil);
  FrameChercherAppels.Top:=35;
  FrameChercherAppels.Parent:= ChercherDesAppelsForm;
end;
```

First, you never need to check if a variable is assigned before you free it, because `TObject.Free` does that. Basically, `X.Free` does `if Assigned(X) then X.Destroy`, so `if Assigned(X) then X.Free` does `if Assigned(X) then if Assigned(X) then X.Destroy` with does one test too many.

Second, your code will free the "statistics" frame, but it will not set the pointer `FrameStatistiquesAppels` to `nil`. Hence, you end up with a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

This is very bad in your case, because if you invoke `OuvrirFrameChercherAppelOnClick` two times in a row, you will invoke `Free` on a dangling pointer. Indeed, the second time, `FrameStatistiquesAppels` is non-`nil` (it still points to the address of the old object which no longer exists) but it doesn't point to a valid object.

In addition, and this is the third point, if you invoke this method two times in a row, you will have created two "apple" frames, but you only have a pointer to the second one. Hence, you have leaked the first one. If you press this button *N* times, you will have leaked *N* − 1 objects.

You should be able to see the memory increase each time.

The following version resolves all these issues:

```
procedure TChercherDesAppelsForm.OuvrirFrameChercherAppelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(FrameStatistiquesAppels);
  FreeAndNil(FrameChercherAppels);
  FrameChercherAppels := TChercherAppelsFrame.Create(nil);
  FrameChercherAppels.Top := 35;
  FrameChercherAppels.Parent:= ChercherDesAppelsForm;
end;
```

Of course, the second snippet will need to be updated in the same way.

---

All this being said, wouldn't it be simpler to create both frames once at application startup (you could even place them on the form at design time) and then only toggle their visibilities?

```
procedure TChercherDesAppelsForm.OuvrirFrameChercherAppelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FrameStatistiquesAppels.Hide;
  FrameChercherAppels.Show;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very complete answer. Yes, I wanted to do what you mentioned at the end but it is not bad to do that? Besides, how do we do in Delphi to execute actions when launching the application?

Comment: @Ush_63100: No, not really. In your case, you could create both frames in the form's `OnCreate` event handler.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: No problem. If you also do `TChercherAppelsFrame.Create(Self)` (the same thing as `TChercherAppelsFrame.Create(ChercherDesAppelsForm)`) the form will be its "owner" (in addition to the form being the frame's parent) and so the frame will be automatically freed when the form is freed.